# I need to remove the "on page nn" from my DITA-OT 3.6 xrefs

Tags: dita, dita-ot

Would someone have fun telling me this easy info? My xrefs have format="dita", my topics have no other attributes. I have looked for two days now and cannot find anything detailed enough to succeed. I am publishing to PDF through the org.dita.pdf2 plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for "on page" in the pdf plugins folder. You should find the language resource file with the respective string. You should then override this string in your plugin. If this os insufficient, search again for the ID of the respective string in the XSL files for the corresponding template and override this in your plugin.

Comment: The you have to override this: https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/blob/9d0ad7495db0240ef7acee99b3593368acd90a89/src/main/plugins/org.dita.pdf2/cfg/common/vars/en.xml#L136